# How to deactivate security warning error (generated because of SSL) via coding in a web application

Tags: html, asp.net, ssl, iframe, popupwindow

We have built an application with asp.net and vb.net. Our client can integrate this application into their website as an iframe. In our application (the one or clients use it as an iframe ) there is a contact us form which opens as a popup window.

```
<a class="contact-us btn" href="//cs.mypbiz.com/contact.aspx?vacancyid=<%: Vacancy.ID%>" onclick="window.open(this.href,'Job enquiry','width=460,height=580,status=1');return false;">Contact Us</a>
```

That one works fine. But some of our clients has https website.  After integrating the iframe in a https website when user try to open the contact form they get security warning error in all browser.
How do deactivate that error by coding so that the user do not receive the error regardless of whatever website (http or https) they use

screenshot of the iframe with the popup when it integrated in a normal http website
[image]

screenshot of the iframe with the popup when it integrated in a secured website (https website)
[image]

How do deactivate that error by coding so that the user do not receive the error regardless of whatever website (http or https) they use.

Comment: That's not a bug, that's a feature. In other words, this prevents evilsite.com from pretending "I'm cs.mypbiz.com, send me your message!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That idea of security warnings is that only the user can decide to skip the warning. It would be very bad if the insecure site or some attacker in the middle could simply disable such a warning.

Thus instead of disabling the warning you need to fix your site so that the warning vanishes. The problem is not that your site does not support https, but that the certificate is wrong: you access the site as cs.mypbiz.com but the certificate is for portals.mypbiz.com. To fix this you need to either change the URL you provide or to get another certificate which includes the correct hostname. Apart from that you should also fix all the other problems noticed in the [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=cs.mypbiz.com).

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell you client to make the request for the iframe like this

```
<iframe src="/your-iframe-link" />
```

not like this

```
<iframe src="http://your-iframe-link" />
```

If this doesn't work too you have to implement SSL on the server holding your navigation page so clients can use https:// for your iframe reference. This will not cause warning in the opposite case when requesting https iframe over http page.